# Unzip a file contains multiple text files using copy activity in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an issue while unzipping a file that contains multiple text files. I have used copy activity to unzip the file but its creating folder with name as zip file (folder named as source zip file) and can see my text files inside that. My requirement is text files should be placed in the folder I wanted.

I tried below copy sink properties but nothing working:

1. `flatten hierarchy+ @{item().name}`
2. `none+ @{item(),name}`
3. `preserver hierarchy+ @{item().name}`

Comment: Do you want to remove the ".zip" contained in the file name after unzipping and copying?   I think you can try this expression `@replace({item().name},'.zip','')`.

Comment: zip file contains 3 text files in it and need to unzip and copy those text files into separate  folder but when i try to unzip its create folder with name same as zip file which i don't want

Answer (score 2):

Please unselect `Preserve zip file name as folder` at the source tab. ADF will not create the `xxx.zip` folder.

[image]

At **source** side dataset, we can select `ZipDeflate` as Compression type.
[image]

At **sink** side dataset,  select `none` as Compression type.
[image]